# Can afficio be used to mean "approach?"

Tags: grammar-choice, latin-to-english-translation

In English, we can say "I made towards the abandoned building" which means the same thing as "I approach the abandoned building."

I'm guessing it may be possible, via a circumlocuitous route, to interpret "Afficio ad locum" in this way:
"I influence (myself) towards the place."

So what do you think Latinists? Is it possible to say in Latin "Afficio ad locum" to mean "I approach the place?"

Comment: I've never seen this directional use of _afficio_. In any case, since this verb is transitive, I guess that the intransitive uses of this verb would rather involve the middle-passive morphology, i.e. _afficior_.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to the titular question is “no,” but surprisingly the most literal and straightforward translation would actually work! (If you are willing to tolerate Late Latin, at least.)

What's “make”? *Facere*, right? Now thanks to [Lewis & Short, sense I.B.10](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfacio):

> In late Lat., (se) facere aliquo, *to betake one's self* to any place: “intra limen sese facit,” *App. 5, p. 159, 25*; “without se: homo meus coepit ad stelas facere,” *Petr. 62*: “ad illum ex Libya Hammon facit,” *Tert. Pall. 3*.

… you can say: *Ad aedificium relictum feci.*